# How do I import an external text file from a website and use a list from inside it

Tags: python, list

I'm having trouble trying to make this work

```
import requests
import random
response = requests.get("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/480168592164257792/557872162661335040/aaaaa.txt")
data = response.text
for line in data:
    print(line)
```

I am trying to pull a txt file from the internet, and be able to use the list inside of the text file.

Right now all it does is assume each letter is a different string(?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute `response.text` is a string, so iterating over it will give you individual chars. You can split the string by spaces (or maybe be newlines) to get what you need (I also added a few print statements to show the steps):

```
import requests
response = requests.get(
    "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/480168592164257792/557872162661335040/aaaaa.txt")
print('response.text type:', type(response.text))
print('response.text len:', len(response.text))
print(response.text)

print()
print('splitting by spaces:')
for i, s in enumerate(response.text.split()):
    print(i, s)

print()
print('splitting by newlines:')
for i, line in enumerate(response.text.split('\n')):
    print(i, line)
```

The code gives this output:

```
response.text type: <class 'str'>
response.text len: 21
a = ["please","work"]

splitting by spaces:
0 a
1 =
2 ["please","work"]

splitting by newlines:
0 a = ["please","work"]
```

---

@bruno suggested in a comment to use [`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines); this will work even if the response is bytes, since there also exists the method [`bytes.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.splitlines).

Comment: You want data.splitlines() instead of data.split("\n") (can make a difference if response.text is a byte string and uses another newline marker).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I added that observation to my answer

Answer (score 1):

response.text seems to be characters, if you loop over them you get each string. (Read about how Python handles strings).
In this case Python doesn't know what a "line" is. So split the data with newlines and try again:

```
import requests
import random
  response = requests.get("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/480168592164257792/557872162661335040/aaaaa.txt")
data = response.text
for line in data.split("\n"):
  print(line)
```

Comment: You want `data.splitlines()`  instead of `data.split("\n")` (can make a difference if `response.text` is a byte string and uses another newline marker).